# What is the importance of a high modulation depth?

Tags: optics, waves, experimental-physics, photonics

I understand that the modulation depth of a  sinusoidally modulated signal can be defined as the modulation amplitude divided by the mean value, as explained [here](https://www.rp-photonics.com/modulation_depth.html).

But why would one wish for a high modulation depth in an experiment? What advantages does it bring?

Some [articles](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/adom.201600697) state that they have achieved a high modulation depth of 90%, but isn't what matter that amplitude of the signal or its "shape"/frequency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The higher the modulation index is in a double sideband AM system (DSB) the higher is the SNR when detected; this is true for both coherent and non-coherent (envelope) detection methods.

Write the DSB-AM signal as $$x(t)=A_c(1+\kappa m(t)) \rm{sin} (\omega_c T) \tag{1}\label{1}$$ where $0 < \kappa \le 1$ is the modulation index, $-1 \le m(t) \le 1$ the modulation (information bearing signal) and $\omega_c$ is the carrier frequency whose amplitude is $A_c$. Assume that the signal is received in white normal noise of intensity $\mathcal N_0$ then for coherent detection the signal is detected with $$(SNR)_D=2(SNR)_T \frac{\kappa^2 \langle m^2 \rangle}{1+{\kappa^2 \langle m^2 \rangle}} \tag{2}\label{2}$$
Here $\langle m^2 \rangle$ is the variance of the modulation, and  $(SNR)_T=\frac{P_T}{N_T}$ with $N_T=2\mathcal N_0 W$ and $P_T=\frac{1}{2}A_c^2(1+{\kappa^2 \langle m^2 \rangle})$ being the received RF noise and RF transmit powers, resp.

For non-coherent detection the received SNR is $$(SNR)_D=\frac{2(SNR)_T}{1+\frac{2}{(SNR)_T}} \frac{\kappa^2 \langle m^2 \rangle}{(1+{\kappa^2 \langle m^2 \rangle})^2} \tag{3}\label{3}$$

As you can see from $\eqref{2}$ and $\eqref{3}$ both coherent and non-coherent detection SNR are monotonically increasing function of the modulation index $\kappa$, higher the index $\kappa$ the higher the $SNR$ is.

An all-around excellent book to read on this (chapter 8) and  also on many other subjects is

[1] Ziemer and Tranter: PRINCIPLES OF COMMUNICATIONS: Systems, Modulation, and Noise, Wiley 7th ed.

A general note of caution: in practice, the true performance of DSB-AM with high modulation index is quite sensitive to both transmitter and receiver nonlinearities that are always present and will inevitably degrade the *theoretical* SNR discussed here.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I am taking some of these equations for granted as I have never seen them before, but mathematically they make sense and show that the SNR increases with $\kappa$ .
Thank you

Comment: Forgot to add that "modulation depth of a sinusoidally modulated signal can be defined as the modulation amplitude divided by the mean value" should be other way around, that is modulation depth of a sinusoidally modulated signal can be defined as the the mean value divided by modulation amplitude, even this definition is quite lame though. The correct definition of $\kappa$ is by $\eqref{1}$ where $|m(t)| \le 1$....

Comment: The truth is that I am not sure whether your RP Photonics is really about DSB-AM and not PM (phase modulation), but even if PM the conclusion is the same, higher SNR for larger $\kappa$

Comment: The RP photonics article is talking about intensity modulation.

Answer (score 2):

In the context of intensity-modulated optical communications systems, a high modulation depth is preferred because it implies high efficiency, where efficiency is defined in terms of bits of data transferred per joule of energy.

Only the modulation amplitude contributes a useful signal. The power that is present at the minimum of the signal doesn't carry any information. It increases the energy sent per bit without improving the signal-to-noise ratio of the system.

Practically, though, the goal is usually to achieve a modulation depth that is "high enough" rather than to maximize it, because beyond a certain point there are diminishing returns for additional improvements in modulation depth.

You would see a similar benefit (i.e. better signal discrimination with less optical power) if you were using a high-modulation-depth modulator, for example, to control the exposure of a sample in a fluorescence experiment (you wouldn't want to continue exposing the sample to pump light during the emission phase of the experiment).

And, as presented in your linked article, a high modulation-depth absorber is also essential to constructing a high-quality mode-locked laser.